# How can I change every Format on every field in a database?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've been tasked with making a series of changes to an access database.  One of them is to change the format in the database from UK to Australian.

The "cost" fields in the database have the type of Currency, but the "Format" is "£#,##0.00;-£#,##0.00".  Changing Format to "Currency" makes it display as $, but these fields are everywhere across different tables in this database.

Is there a central spot to change it, or if not, is there some VBA that I could write to do this?  I attempted to do it via VBA script, using a For Each iterator over every table, but I don't understand how to change the "Format" field via that method.

Comment: It's not the tables, but the controls on forms and reports that display the values, that must be changed. So iterate Forms, Controls, Property Format and adjust when £ is found.

Comment: Is this application running in the UK or Australia? In some cases you may be able to change the Regional Settings to get the results you want, however if you're in the UK, I doubt you want to set them to Australian else unintended results may appear with other products. You can change masks and formats, but that may be brutal. We deployed to 70+ countries, but since all users were 'US' employees, we required them to stick with English (US).

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn The format field is set to "£#,##0.00;-£#,##0.00" on every single field of type "Currency", my machine is set to Australia region but it doesn't help :(

Comment: I just replaced my answer with a description of what I discovered in testing, plus two ways that you can change the number format. One at design time, the other at run time.

Answer (score 2):

First, please read the following and see if that fixes your issue with the currency formats: http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Using-the-Currency-field-data-type---without-the-hassle

If not, read on...

After further testing, it seems changing the 'format' property for a field in the table doesn't help you at all with existing forms/reports. Therefore you have two options to solve the format issue: (Method 1) is to change the design view of all forms/reports to use an explicit format; or (Method 2) use some VBA code to set the format property at run-time (when the object is opened). If you have many fields to change, option (1) will be easier. Read the instructions for option (Method 2) then you get to decide.

The following VBA code can loop thru all reports and forms. I currently have it set to only process one form and one report, and I suggest you start small, then when satisfied with the results, process all objects.

Look at each place where I have used '###' as it explains something you can/should change.

***Method 1:***

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' NOTE!!!! Look at all comments containing '###' for notes
Sub Fix_Reports_and_Forms()
    Change_Form_Properties
    Change_Report_Properties
End Sub

Function Change_Form_Properties()
Dim dbs         As DAO.Database
Dim ctr         As Container
Dim doc         As Document
Dim frm         As Form
Dim ctl         As Control
Dim ObjectName  As String
Dim i           As Integer
Dim bChg        As Boolean

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set ctr = dbs.Containers!Forms

    For Each doc In ctr.Documents
        ObjectName = doc.Name

        '### For testing, I suggest you change the following code to select only ONE Form. Later, remove the IF to do all.
        If ObjectName = "Table1" Then  ' ### If you want to process ALL forms, remove this 'IF' and matching 'End If'
            DoCmd.OpenForm ObjectName, acViewDesign
            DoCmd.Minimize
            Set frm = Forms(doc.Name)
            Debug.Print "Form: " & frm.Name & vbTab & "Ctls: " & frm.Controls.Count
            bChg = False

            For Each ctl In frm.Controls                    ' Loop thru all controls
                If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then         ' Is this a TextBox?
                    Debug.Print vbTab & ctl.Name & vbTab & "Type: " & ctl.ControlType & vbTab & "Format: " & ctl.Properties("Format")
                    If ctl.Properties("Format") <> "" Then
                        ' Add code to test if some currency format
                        If ctl.Properties("Format") = "Currency" Then
                            ctl.Properties("Format") = "£#,##0.00;-£#,##0.00"
                            bChg = True
                        ElseIf ctl.Properties("Format") = "$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00" Then
                            ctl.Properties("Format") = "£#,##0.00;-£#,##0.00"
                            bChg = True
                        Else        ' ### any other formats that need to be changed?
                            ' Add code if needed
                        End If
                    Else
                        ' ### Here I am checking for a specific field name as ControlSource
                        ' This is not needed if you can identify controls by above code.
                        If ctl.Properties("ControlSource") = "CurrFld" Then
                            ctl.Properties("Format") = "£#,##0.00;-£#,##0.00"
                            bChg = True
                        End If
                    End If
                ElseIf ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then        ' ### Add code for other control types as needed
                    ' Do something if necessary
                End If
            Next ctl
            If bChg = True Then     ' Save changes
                DoCmd.Close acForm, ObjectName, acSaveYes
            Else                    ' Do not Save
                DoCmd.Close acForm, ObjectName, acSaveNo
            End If

        End If              '### Remove if processing ALL Form Names
    Next doc

End Function

Function Change_Report_Properties()
Dim dbs         As DAO.Database
Dim ctr         As Container
Dim doc         As Document
Dim rpt         As Report
Dim ctl         As Control
Dim ObjectName  As String
Dim i           As Integer
Dim bChg        As Boolean

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set ctr = dbs.Containers!Reports

    For Each doc In ctr.Documents
        ObjectName = doc.Name

        '### For testing, I suggest you change the following code to select only ONE Form. Later, remove the IF to do all.
        If ObjectName = "Table1" Then  ' ### If you want to process ALL Reports, remove this 'IF' and matching 'End If'
            DoCmd.OpenReport ObjectName, acViewDesign
            DoCmd.Minimize
            Set rpt = Reports(doc.Name)
            Debug.Print "Report: " & rpt.Name & vbTab & "Ctls: " & rpt.Controls.Count
            bChg = False

            For Each ctl In rpt.Controls
                If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox Then
                    Debug.Print vbTab & ctl.Name & vbTab & "Type: " & ctl.ControlType & vbTab & "Format: " & ctl.Properties("Format")
                    If ctl.Properties("Format") <> "" Then
                        ' Add code to test if some currency format
                        If ctl.Properties("Format") = "Currency" Then
                            ctl.Properties("Format") = "£#,##0.00;-£#,##0.00"
                            bChg = True
                        ElseIf ctl.Properties("Format") = "$#,##0.00;-$#,##0.00" Then
                            ctl.Properties("Format") = "£#,##0.00;-£#,##0.00"
                            bChg = True
                        Else        ' any other formats that need to be changed?
                            ' Add code if needed
                        End If
                    Else
                        '### Here I am checking for a specific field name as ControlSource
                        If ctl.Properties("ControlSource") = "CurrFld" Then
                            ctl.Properties("Format") = "£#,##0.00;-£#,##0.00"
                            bChg = True
                        End If
                    End If
                ElseIf ctl.ControlType = acComboBox Then        ' ### Add code for other control types as needed
                    ' Do something if necessary
                End If
            Next ctl
            If bChg = True Then     ' Save changes
                DoCmd.Close acReport, ObjectName, acSaveYes
            Else                    ' Do not Save
                DoCmd.Close acReport, ObjectName, acSaveNo
            End If

        End If              '### Remove if processing ALL Report Names
    Next doc

End Function
```

***Method 2***

I found a method of changing the format at Run-Time at this site: http://donnedwards.openaccess.co.za/2009/03/microsoft-access-and-ten-year-old.html

The steps involved may prove too difficult if you have many fields that need to have the format changed. Here are the steps required, followed by some sample code.

1. Open the form/report in design view
2. Open the properties for the 'Detail Section'
3. In the TAG property, list every control name where you want to change the format, delimited with comma's.
4. Add a Form/Report 'On Open' event and insert the code shown below.
5. Save the changes
6. Run the report/form

   ```
   Option Compare Database
   Option Explicit

   Private Sub Report_Open(Cancel As Integer)
   '
   '// Fix up CURRENCY formatting
   '
   Dim strField As String, strTag As String, n As Long
       strTag = Me.Detail.Tag
       If Len(strTag) > 2 Then
           strTag = strTag & ","
           n = InStr(1, strTag, ",")
           While n > 0
               strField = Mid$(strTag, 1, n - 1)
               strTag = Mid$(strTag, n + 1)
               'Me(strField).Format = "Currency"
               Me(strField).Format = "£#,##0.00;-£#,##0.00"
               n = InStr(1, strTag, ",")
           Wend
       End If
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Thanks this looks like the most promising response thus far.  Can I ask a question - are you using the inbuilt access VBA editor to do this stuff?  I am used to the Visual Studio IDE and wonderful intellisense, and the intellisense in Access seems a bit haphazard.

Comment: Yes, I'm just using VBA editor built into Access (Office 2010). You should be able to just copy the code, paste into a module and run it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate through the [TableDefs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff820997.aspx) and call [SetProperty](http://allenbrowne.com/func-DAO.html#SetPropertyDAO) for each field where you wish to change the format.

Comment: Thanks for that John. I did try this approach via VBA in Access but I didn't get very far.  Do you have any sample code that might help?

Comment: @LewisCianci - what does that mean - you didn't get very far? Can you show your code you tried and what happened or didn;t happen that was supposed to? DId it change the field formats in the table? Do you have form fields that you need to change as well